# Loop through json with random keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I iterate trough a json with random keys? For example:

```
{
  "-KI4TtMlcCgy489krrRK" : {
    "name" : "apple",
    "text" : "green"
  },
  "-KI4TycSzSXwSviWQf5C" : {
    "name" : "banana",
    "text" : "yellow"
  },
  "-KI4U11GePHK9IdeROt7" : {
    "name" : "carrot",
    "text" : orange"
  }
}
```

I am trying to return:

- apple - green
- banana - yellow
- carrot - orange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do a `for in` loop. Then you get the `key` and can do whatever you want to.

```js
var data = {
  "-KI4TtMlcCgy489krrRK" : {
    "name" : "apple",
    "text" : "green"
  },
  "-KI4TycSzSXwSviWQf5C" : {
    "name" : "banana",
    "text" : "yellow"
  },
  "-KI4U11GePHK9IdeROt7" : {
    "name" : "carrot",
    "text" : "orange"
  }
};

for( var key in data ) {
    if( data.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(" - " + data[key].name + " - "+ data[key].text);
    }
}
```